# GoogleMaps API Json parsing in Python using ijson

Tags: python, json, google-maps, pandas, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to parse the JSON response from the GoogleMaps API to read values from a nested dict into a Pandas DataFrame.  The structure of the JSON response is shown below.

I'm trying to create a DataFrame called 'address_components' with ('types', 'short_name', 'long_name') as the column headers and the respective values from each address query as rows.

I've tried to use ijson:

```
from ijson import items
import ijson
f = urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2022+Boren+Ave%2C+Seattle+98101')

objects = list(ijson.items(f, 'results.address_components'))

objects
```

Out: []

My problem is successfully traversing the nested dicts.

I've also reviewed the [GoogleMaps GeoLocator API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding), and the [GoogleMaps JSON parsing docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#ParsingJSON).  [This solution seems to solve the problem, but on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634810/how-to-parse-specific-googlemaps-api-webservices-json-repsonse)

Not helping me to reach into the nest...

```
    "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) for that::

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2022+Boren+Ave%2C+Seattle+98101'

r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    r.raise_for_status()

results = json.loads(r.text)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results'], 'address_components')

print(df)
```

Test:

```
In [17]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(results['results'], 'address_components')
Out[17]:
       long_name   short_name                                     types
0           2022         2022                           [street_number]
1   Boren Avenue    Boren Ave                                   [route]
2       Belltown     Belltown                 [neighborhood, political]
3        Seattle      Seattle                     [locality, political]
4    King County  King County  [administrative_area_level_2, political]
5     Washington           WA  [administrative_area_level_1, political]
6  United States           US                      [country, political]
7          98121        98121                             [postal_code]
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.  Apparently I'm not yet allowed to say so officially as when I checked the box it told me I wasn't a credible respondent to my question...  In any case, thanks very much.